# Twitter Anywhere Tweetbox modal / popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, twitter-anywhere

I want the tweet box to appear (using anywhere) in a modal / popup box (Kind of like how FB.ui works ) While the login etc are automatically in a popup window , But the actual tweet this textbox comes up on the main page. The documentation is very vague about how to incorporate the tweet this box in an iframe or a modal. Can anyone help me with this ?

-Tanker

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [web intents](https://dev.twitter.com/web/intents) for that: